# Running weekly sceduled project with different input data on QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-server, input

I would like to run a QGIS project with a QGIS server, weekly scheduled. I wish the project to run with a different input data, a shapefile layer.

Could such a setup be automatized with QGIS server?

Comment: Sure, but what exactly should happen?

Comment: QGIS Server is for serving map related content. Does your content need updated weekly?

Comment: Yeah, I get a weekly xls. file which I can geocode to a shape file, somehow. Then I need to run the project weekly to produce a map.